# PHP For Loop Outputting Incorrect String Position Data

Tags: php, xampp

I have this for loop I am running on a string of several hundred characters. when I echo out the string position, the position comes back as "10", but the range of the loop is 65 to 80. Please see code below.

```php
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed 
    nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
    Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. 
    Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.";

for ($i = 80; $i > 65; $i--) {
    echo $i; //this outputs correctly-- i.e. "8079787776 etc..."
    if ($string[$i] == ' ') {
        $test = strpos($string, $string[$i]);
        echo $test;
        // $test is outputting "10".
        $leave = strstr($string, $test, true);
        echo $leave; // this outputs the text at position "10"
        // which verifies what I think is going on. 
        break;
    }
}
```

The expected result is the nearest space's position to position 80 would be displayed in `echo $test`, but what is being displayed instead is position 10.

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: You are passing the whole string to `strpos` so you are returning the first space in the whole string, not your intended range (which is still weird, it should be 5). But having your `if` in place, couldn't you just return `$i`?

Comment: On the strpos you are passing it a space not the offset. using $i+1 will give you the position of the first char of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) describe the return value of the strpos function:

> strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

This function will therefore return the position of the first occurence in the string, regardless of the counter value in the loop.

You should propably use the offset:

```
$test = strpos($string, $string[$i], $i);
```